# Separate scatterplots and add line

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, scatter3d

I have a data frame with grouped datasets, each group has 12 rows and 2 columns with the third column being a categorical variable.
I am trying to plot 3 different scatterplots (as a function of the categorical variable) with fitted lines but so far I'm only able to have all data points in one plot. Please help :)

[image: Data.tibble]

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
Data.tibble <- read_excel('')
Graph<-Data.tibble%>%
ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y))+
geom_point(aes(color=factor(Category)))
```

Comment: `... + facet_wrap(~Category)`

Comment: `... + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)` to add the line of fit.

Answer (score 0):

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

### Data

```
df <-
  tibble(
    category = rep(1:3, each = 4),
    x = rep(seq(0,360,120), 3),
    #Random data 
    y = rnorm(12)
  ) %>% 
  #Transform category variable in a factor
  mutate(category = as.factor(category))
```

### Plot code

```
df %>% 
  # Defining aesthetics
  ggplot(aes(x,y,col = category))+
  geom_point()+
  # Facetting plot by category
  facet_grid(rows = vars(category))+
  # Fitting line
  geom_smooth()
```

#### Plot output

[image]